# How to call two different route file from index.js file?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have different two routes named: "route1" and "route2"

Using index.js file I can use **app.use(route1)** file but not able to use route2.js file.

> Index.js contain

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();

var apiRoute = require('./apiRoute');
var apiRoute2 = require('./apiRoute2');
app.use(apiRoute);
app.listen(3000);
```

Where apiRoute has all the GET HTTP methods and apiRoute2 has all the POST methods.

Comment: What about `app.use(route2)`??

Comment: What do you mean by *"not able to use"*? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add more details

Comment: Here is my index.js file content, edited in question.

Comment: @Subburaj, route2 is a file now named apiRoute2 file. an export module.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek, I've tried to use two files in single index file.

Comment: Why don't you just add `app.use(apiRoute2);` just below the `app.use(apiRoute);` line?

Comment: add this `app.use(apiRoute2);`

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek, I have a confusion about not to use multiple app.use() thank you it worked for me.

Comment: @sultanaslam, I have confusion about, multiple time use app.use(). Thank you it worked for me!

Comment: Where does your confusion come from? It's totally normal thing to do. Consider an app where you need to have a global middleware, e.x. body-parser, and also you need to have routes in your app. It's already two `.use` usages! ;) Don't worry, using multiple `.use()` is alright

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek, I have referred some fundamental examples to configure a route using index.js file, most of the examples has only one route included. That's why I've misunderstood that concept. But it is cleared now...! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm posting my suggestion from the comments.

Just add `app.use(apiRoute2);` below the `app.use(apiRoute);` line, like this:

```
app.use(apiRoute);
app.use(apiRoute2);
```

Also, to address your confusion about using multiple `.use()` calls, also I'm pasting my comment here:

It's totally normal thing to do. Consider an app where you need to have a global middleware, e.x. body-parser, and also you need to have routes in your app. It's already two `.use()` usages! ;) Don't worry, using multiple `.use()` is alright

Answer (score 1):

You might want to split your urls so that its easy while calling these APIs

```
app.use('/route1', apiRoute);
app.use('/route2', apiRoute2);
```

replace 'route1' and 'route2' with any string. Now while accessing these APIs your url will be like **http://localhost:3000/route1/something** or **http://localhost:3000/route2/somethingelse**

Answer (score 0):

**Route 1 file**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.all('/',(req,res,next)=>{

      res.send("hey resonse from route 1");

});

module.exports = router;
```

**Route 2 file**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.all('/',(req,res,next)=>{

      res.send("hey resonse from route 2");

});

module.exports = router;
```

**Index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();

var route1 = require('./route1');
var route2 = require('./route2');

app.use('/route1',route1);
app.use('/route2',route2);
app.listen(3000);
```